# Hbase Error while connecting from Java API

Tags: hbase, hortonworks-sandbox

I am getting below error when I execute a JAVA API code to connect Hbase table using below code

## Java code

```
        HBaseConfiguration.addHbaseResources(configuration);    
        LoadIncrementalHFiles loadFfiles = new LoadIncrementalHFiles(configuration);    
        HTable hTable = new HTable(configuration, tableName);   
        loadFfiles.doBulkLoad(new Path(pathToHFile), hTable);   
        System.out.println("Bulk Load Completed..");
```

## Error

6/07/22 10:08:02 ERROR zookeeper.ZooKeeperNodeTracker: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismat
ch with the one configured in the master.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one conf
igured in the master.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RootRegionTracker.waitRootRegionLocation(RootRegionTracker.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:849)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:962) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:860)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:962) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:864)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:821)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.finishSetup(HTable.java:234)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.(HTable.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.(HTable.java:133)
        at com.HBase.BulkLoad.HbaseBulkLoadDriver.run(HbaseBulkLoadDriver.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at com.HBase.BulkLoad.HbaseBulkLoadDriver.main(HbaseBulkLoadDriver.java:34)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

Comment: AS your HBase cluster is configured right with Zookeeper!! issue will be in communication between the HBase services zookeeper . make sure that your HBASE_CONF_DIR  is added/referred with your code.

Comment: Can you explain me clearly what I need to be done as I am new to this

Comment: Configuration conf = new Configuration(); 
conf.addResource(new Path("path to hbase-site.xml"));

Add this, If you using HBase conf add the properties manually.

Comment: path to hbase is /etc/hbase/conf?

Comment: yes and make sure that your HBase configurations are set to you classpath.

Comment: I added,error is not coming but it is not running,it was not comingup with mapper task completed and reducer too

Comment: Similarly add Hadoop_conf_dir also to this.

Comment: Anything else I need to add apart from Hadoop conf

Comment: I added Hadoop_conf_dir too but it is not working,if you have time can we meet up in skype for further discussion so that it will be helpful.

Comment: Configuration configuration = getConf();
        configuration.addResource(new Path("/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml")); 
        configuration.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));